# Failed to load viewstate.The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the cntrl tree that was used to save viewstate during

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error

> "Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request. "

when I try to submit a page where I applied some logic on GridView rowdatabound to alter the RowSpan. On commenting this event there is no error.

here is the code :

```
    int firstRow;
    string previousCat;
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var drv = e.Row.DataItem as QCParameters;

            if (previousCat == drv.AuditTypeValue)
            {
                //If it's the same category as the previous one
                //Increment the rowspan
                if (GridView1.Rows[firstRow].Cells[0].RowSpan == 0)
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[firstRow].Cells[0].RowSpan = 2;
                    GridView1.Rows[firstRow].Cells[5].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[firstRow].Cells[0].RowSpan += 1;
                    GridView1.Rows[firstRow].Cells[5].RowSpan += 1;
                }
                //Remove the cell
                if (e.Row.Cells.Count > 5)
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(5);
                e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            else //It's a new category
            {                
                e.Row.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                //Maintain the category in memory
                previousCat = drv.AuditTypeValue;
                firstRow = e.Row.RowIndex;
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you remove cells and than during postback (when the control tree is recreated) it does not match and the ViewState cant be loaded.
One possible solution would be to "hide" the cells instead by setting: `e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;`
Not Visible controls will not be rendered but will still be part of the page control tree.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false; worked better for me.

Comment: @BhaweshPaliwal Quite right. That was what I was thinking about also.